# jenkins : snaphot artifact in release build

Tags: maven, plugins, jenkins, nexus

I'm using jenkins maven release plugin in order to make release builds.

When I perform a release build, the release is corrected deployed in Nexus but if I can't download the artifact build in Jenkins UI : when I click on the release build, the build artifact displays is the last Snaphot and not the release.

Why?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't understand this: "I can't download the artifact build in Jenkins UI : when I click on the release build".  How are you trying to download the artifact in Jenkins?  What exactly are you clicking on?

Comment: On the Jenkins home page, i click on the job. Then in the builds history, I click on a release build (release build have a special icon : yellow box). Then I click on module building and then I have building artifacts.

Answer (score 0):

The released artifact is in:

```
target\checkout\target
```